# makefile C strange bash command behavior

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I am trying to create makefile file with clean.

My clean looks like (it's supposed to erase enything from location except *.c source files).

```
clean:
    rm !(*.c)
```

When I am trying to execute `make clean` in terminal i get

```
User 1# make clean
rm !(*.c)
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

But when i type `rm !(*.c)` into terminal it works fine.

Why command written in makefile does not work?

Comment: It's safer to be explicit about which file you want to pass to `rm`; you don't know when you might create a non-`.c` file you want to keep, but forget to update the recipe.

Comment: I am fully aware of risk but for now I just wanna make rm !(*.c) work.

Comment: this line: rm !(*.c) will also delete you makefile.  Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You are running `bash` in your terminal. `make` is running that recipe line through the default `SHELL` which is `/bin/sh`.

You can set `SHELL := /bin/bash` in your makefile to select a different shell for make to execute its recipe lines or you can manually run `bash -c 'rm !(*.c)'` as your recipe line or you can use a different method to select the files to clean.

Update from comments (thanks @chepner):

`extglob` must be enabled for `!(*.c)` to be used. It must also be set before a line using it is parsed (so `bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; rm !(*.c)'` does not work).

The available options are therefore to use `bash -O extglob -c 'rm !(*.c)'` (which is likely the best answer) to set `SHELL := bash -O extglob` (which works in make 3.81 but needs to be done differently for newer versions of make) or to use a heredoc.

```
bash <<EOF
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*.c)
EOF
```

Though I don't believe the heredoc option is possible from within a makefile recipe.

Comment: Note that you'll also have to ensure that the extended glob option is set if going the `bash` route, which I think can only be done if you explicitly run `bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; rm !(*.c)'`.

Comment: @chepner Quite possibly. I assumed that was on by default in whatever version of `bash` they were using but they might just be setting that in an init file.

Comment: It still throws me an error that ( character is unexpected tried 3 versions with SHELL variable with bash -c 'rm !(*.c)' and bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; rm !(*.c)'

Comment: @user2184057 What error are you getting from the `SHELL :=` version *exactly*? Does it still start with `/bin/sh`?

Comment: For the answers till now

    Omnislash 1 # make clean

    bash -c 'rm !(*.c)'

    bash: -c: line 0: Syntax Error Near Unexpected Token `('

    bash: -c: line 0: `rm !(*.c)'

    make: *** [clean] Error 1

    Omnislash 1 # make clean

    bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; rm !(*.c)'

    bash: -c: line 0: Syntax Error Near Unexpected Token `('

    bash: -c: line 0: `shopt -s extglob; rm !(*.c)'

    make: *** [clean] Error 1

Comment: Error with the SHELL := is the same as with other versions in another means

make clean
bash rm !(*.c)
/bin/bash: -c: Syntax Error Near Unexpected Token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `bash rm !(*.c)'
make: *** [clean] Error 1

Comment: It appears that `shopt -s extglob` must be executed before a line using an extended pattern is *parsed*, meaning something like `shopt -s extglob; rm !(*.c)` will not work. This means you cannot use it inside the argument to the `-c` option.

Comment: Ah, I knew I was overlooking an option: `bash -O extglob -c 'rm !(*.c)'`.

Answer (score 1):

Better to just use portable shell instead of trying to shoe-horn bash-specific features:

```
ls -1 | grep -v '\.c$' | xargs rm -f
```

I'll admit this doesn't work so well if your filenames may contain whitespace.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend parsing the output from `ls` but the general idea here is certainly a good one. (I'd probably use `find ... -print0 | xargs -o rm -f`.)

Comment: You mean `xargs -0` not `xargs -o`.  You'd have to use `-maxdepth 1` if you use `find` to duplicate the glob, and unfortunately the `-print0` flag etc. are not standard; they only exist in GNU find.  I didn't feel like I should use them in a post about using portable versions of tools :).

Comment: Yeah, typo as I was running out the door. And yes, portability suffers a bit there. Though mostly on the `xargs` side since you can always use `-printf "..\0"` on the `find` end. And even manually loop with `read` in `bash` if necessary.